# Compare Datagridview and Database field for Update Process

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm doing winforms.. In that I'm comparing the datagridview column value and db value..

If the `DataGridView` column exist in db I want to do update process if not exist, I want to do Insert process.

I tried this code

```
string resultJewelId = null; string QueryJewelId = null;

    private void AddStockTable()
    {
        try
        {
            Sqlcon = objDB.DBConnection();


            QueryJewelId= "Select JewelId from tblStock";

            Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(QueryJewelId, Sqlcon);


            dr = Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        resultJewelId = dr.GetString(0);

                        if (resultJewelId == dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString())
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Update process");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Insert Process");
                        }
                    }
                } 

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }
```

While condition working fine.. But I don't know how to move next row value in for loop..

Kindly support me.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Once you execute your `while (dr.Read())` statement you must reset your `DataReader`.  But the only way to do that is call this line again for each row:

`dr = Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();`

before your while loop.  Incredibly inefficient but it will fix your issue.